# How to run Time Series Regression with years, countries, and multiple values in R?

Tags: r, categories, multivariate-time-series

I think I know what I need to do, I just don't know how to make it work.

Example of Data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIgPA.png)

I have decades of data in Excel in that format, which I uploaded to R. I believe I need to convert it to a time series or date format somehow, but retain the countries as categories so I can run the following regressions:

```
y ~ x1+x2 
x1 ~ x2
y ~ x1
```

Can anyone share code/packages that can help me accomplish this? It feels simple, but I could not find any examples in a few hours of searching. Would `ggplot` also be recommended for producing figures with this data?

I tried converting it to `as.xts`, but that did not work, likely because of my poor understanding and the Country column. My failed attempt below:

```
modelts=as.xts(model1[,-1],order.by=as.Date(model1[,1],format='%m%d%Y'))
```

Comment: Do u want to create a data frame of each country across time or cross-section for each time period?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a great fit for a tsibble:

```
as_tsibble(your_df, key = "Country", index = "Year")
```

You can then use the wonderful tidyverts tools:
[Tidy tools for time series](https://tidyverts.org/)

These use ggplot2 and dplyr.

A great guide for these tools is:
[Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3rd ed)](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)